# Turning off the computer fully from hardware buttons

Tags: boot, motherboard

This is probably a retarded question but I just finished a new build using an ASUS M5A99FX PRO motherboard, and after turning it on once to check that everything worked last night, I tried turning it on again today to install the OS off a USB but am getting a black screen right off the bat--no boot sequence, nothing. I'm guessing that this is because after exiting the bios last night I let it continue booting into the nothingness that is the lack of an OS, and then failed to fully turn it off in order to get back to the boot sequence.

I read the manual and all it mentions is some 'soft-off' state, but nothing about 'hard off'. How do I get the boot sequence back?

Comment: Your thought process is flawed if there was no OS it would have proceeded very far, what is actually going on, is not clear given the information you provided

Comment: Your Question: `Turning off the computer fully from hardware buttons` Answer: well, just unplug the power cable, pull out any batteries and power the device OFF that way while holding down on the power button. If the hardware buttons are damaged then just bypass everything and kill all the power sources and cables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holding down the power button, unplugging, switching every off, etc. did not work. Finally I just reset the jumper. After that, for some reason absolutely every one of those things worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the power button for several seconds and the power will cycle off. ATX boards are kind of always on, so a true 'off' state requires you turn off your ATX supply. They have little rocker switches on them so you can do that, but most folks never need to.

In your case however, just hold in that power button. Once off, you can let go of the button, wait a second and then press it again to power-on again.

Comment: I've held it down and powered it on again a few times before and after asking this question, but to no avail. Switched the power supply on and off too.

Comment: Interesting. I see your answer. I recommend you find out what revision of the BIOS firmware you have for that board and go check the vendor's site to see if they have a newer version. If so, read all the changelog between your version and the latest to see if this is a known bug they've patched. And in the case that is has been patched, you should then seriously consider updating your BIOS, which only costs you a few minutes of effort.